# Application of Richardson Extrapolation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, extrapolation

Apply Richardson extrapolation to

$ S_{2h} = \frac{2h}{3}[f(x_0) + 4f(x_2) + f(x_4)]$

$S_h =\frac{h}{3}[f(x_0) + 4f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 4f(x_3) + f(x_4)] $
to derive a Newton–Cotes formula based on the $5$ equally spaced points $x_0, x_1 = x_0 + h, x_2 = x_0 + 2h, x_3 = x_0 + 3h, x_4 = x_0 + 4h $ for the approximation of$\int_{x_0}^{x_4}f(x) dx$. 
Verify
that this new formula integrates exactly any quintic polynomial.

This was one of the optional questions on my numerical analysis sheet and I am really confused about how to approach it (We didn't have time to look at it). I am OK, with the basics if the Richardson Extrapolation method, where you increase the least degree in the series of the approximation making it a closer one. Here, however, we don't have series to work with. I was thinking about using the Euler–Maclaurin formula but it seems like an overkill. Every answer/explanation/hint is appreciated.

**Note** I am not looking just for the solution since the deadline has passed away long time ago. I just want to be able to use this approach freely. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richardson extrapolation posits that you have a symmetric analytic function $t \mapsto F(t)$. You wish to know $F(0)$. 
Analyticity means:

$F(h) = F(0) + h^2 F^{(2)}(0) + h^4 F^{(4)}(0) + \ldots$

and

$F(2 h) = F(0) + 2^2 h^2 F^{(2)}(0) + 2^4 h^4 F^{(4)}(0) + \ldots$.

In our case you have the values for $F(h)$ and $F(2 h)$, which are $S_h$ and $S_{2 h}$, respectively. But how you obtain $F(h)$ and $F(2 h)$ is actually irrelevant for extrapolation.

You have two equations and as many unknowns as you wish. Drop the higher-order terms, here all those with $h^4$ and more.

Solve the resulting system for $F(0)$ in terms of $F(h)$ and $F(2 h)$.

Comment: but how do we get to these forms of $F(h)$ and $F(2h)$ given we have just a multiple of $h$

Comment: @asdf: I don't understand your question

Comment: We have that $F(h)=$ constant multiple of $h$ since $F(h)=S_h$. How do we get to the form where we have higher degrees

Comment: The higher degrees are there to begin with. You throw those away, which introduces an error. It's an inexact **extrapolation**. Maybe the reworded answer is clearer.